# Linking Nodejs app container to elastic search container securely (Docker)

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, docker

Elasitc search has no built in security so I need to handle it myself and the best way I thought of doing this to remove public access from it and only allow access from it through an API a node web application.

However I'm still able to access elastic search on port 0.0.0.0:9200, I basically only want the node application to be able to talk to elasticsearch.

```
version: "2"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
  node-bot:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - "./dist:/dist"
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "3030:3005"
    depends_on:
      - "elasticsearch"
```

Hopefully that makes sense, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `ports` from `elasticsearch` definition

Comment: thanks,  Will there be a quick way to test this, like entering the node container and running a curl command?

Comment: Yes, you can use something like `docker exec -t container_name curl http://elasticsearch:9200`. Of course this will only work if you have curl installed in your container

Comment: Awesome that worked, I'll accept the answer. Just a tiny thing can you see any problems with what I'm doing that will cause me problems when I want to scale vertically?

Comment: Well, you won't be able to scale beyond 1 node with docker-compose, if that's what you mean

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought, thanks... So if I wanted to move beyond one node I would effectively have to take it out of docker?

Comment: Absolutely not! There many tools to scale dockerized apps: Kubernetes, Swarm, Nomad, etc.